# Bold & Non-Bold Text In uitextView - iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextview

I'm Using uitextview for showing some detail. I need to achieve the text format as below.

**How ?**

Some text

**Who?**

Some text

Text with the question mark should be Bold letter and other text will be normal. Same for for the other text in the textview

I'm working on multiple language text with the same format.

Can Someone please help me on how to get this format in Xamarin iOS text view. Thanks !!

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, you can mark the answer which will help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSAttributedString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsattributedstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)  to custom the string format:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var textV = new UITextView(new CGRect(100, 100, 300, 300));

    var myMutableString = new NSMutableAttributedString("How ? \n Some text \n Who ? \n Some text");

    var range1 = myMutableString.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString(new NSString("How ?"));
    var range2 = myMutableString.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString(new NSString("Who ?"));

    var range3 = myMutableString.MutableString.LocalizedStandardRangeOfString(new NSString("Some text"));

    myMutableString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24), range1);
    myMutableString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24), range2);

    myMutableString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Font, UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14), range3);

    textV.AttributedText = myMutableString;
    View.AddSubview(textV);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]